# Android, repo sync and unending downloads?

Tags: android, repository

I did 'repo sync' 16 hour ago. My network history shows 5.9 GByte downloaded( and counting), Yet I can't see any directory created in my 'repo-ed' directory. There is a .repo (hidden) directory containing various .git sub-directories though.

**I am confused if this is the normal course of action !!!**

Will the sources' show up after 8-10 GB of downloading ?
info- I'm repo-ing Gingerbread 2.3.7

Answer (score 0):

The download is now complete at ~8 GByte. Now my working directory, where i ran **'repo sync'**, contain all the sources (16 directories excluding .repo ).
As per my experience the course of action is,

- Start download with 'repo sync'. Wait till download is complete.
- If download is interrupted, no need to worry, do 'repo sync' again
  and wait for download to complete.
- Upon download completion working directory will be populated with
  respective source directories.

I hope this helps others !